# How to call function from controller AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, function, controller

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']); 
app.controller("GetTicketDetails", function ($scope, $http) {    
  $scope.GetData = function(){ 
    $http({
        url: "../api/getData",
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.ListTicketDetails = response.data;
        $scope.TotalTickets = response.data.length;
    })
  };

  $scope.DeleteKitchen = function (x) {    
    $http({   
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '../api/Delete_kitchen?Id=' + x,            
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $http({
            url: "../api/getData",
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.ListTicketDetails = response.data;
            $scope.TotalTickets = response.data.length;
        })
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert("Error. while updating user Try Again!");
    });
  };
```

Can i call $scope GetData in DeleteKitchen Success Response to reload the Altered Data ??
In order reduce typing again get data http get request

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is yes.

Explanation:
As long as the function in which you're willing to call `GetData` is inside the controller, you can call.

`$scope` is a function parameter of the controller and whatever is inside that function no matter how deep, it'll be accessible([Refer closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for more info). Once `$scope` is accessible, you can access `GetData`

```
app.controller("GetTicketDetails", function ($scope, $http) { 
    // controller code
    // $scope is accessible everywhere within this no matter how deep.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.DeleteKitchen = function (x) {    
    $http({   
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '../api/Delete_kitchen?Id=' + x,            
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $http({
            url: "../api/getData",
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.ListTicketDetails = response.data;
            $scope.TotalTickets = response.data.length;
            //calling getData again
            $scope.GetData();
        })
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert("Error. while updating user Try Again!");
    });
```

You can do it like this.